Minimal polynomials and field extensions
Let $K|F$ be a field extension and $A$ be a $n$ times $n$ matrix over $F$. Denote $\mbox{Irr}_F(A)(x),\mbox{Irr}_K(A)(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $F$ and $K$ respectively. Is it true that $\mbox{Irr}_F(A)(x)=\mbox{Irr}_K(A)(x)$?

Yes. Let $V$ be the $F[x]$-module whose underlying vector space is $F^n$ and on which $x$ acts via $A$. Then $V$ is a finitely generated module over a PID, and so it decomposes uniquely as a sum
$$
F[x] / (p_1(x)) \oplus F[x] / (p_2(x)) \oplus \ldots \oplus F[x]/ (p_n(x))
$$
where $p_i | p_{i+1}$ (these are the invariant factors -- unique up to associates, so unique if we require them to be monic). The minimal polynomial is clearly $p_n(x)$. When we extend scalars to $K$, we must get the same sequence of polynomials by unicity, so the minimal polynomial must be the same.  (Note that the $p_i$ are, in general, far from irreducible, and extending scalars might indeed cause them to have smaller-degree factors, which is fine.)

Thank you. May I bother you a little? I see this result on Hoffmann and Kunze linear algebra book. So where can I found a more elementary proof? In other words, a proof that I can use in a Linear Algebra course for engineers for example?

@KaiqueRoberto For a different proof, consider the $K$-vector space $M_n(K)$. If the degree of the minimal polynomial is $r$, the elements of this vector space $I, \ldots, A^{r-1}$ must be linearly independent. It follows that they are linearly independent in the $L$-vector space $M_n(L)$. (You need to prove that extending scalars can't break linear independence, which isn't totally trivial, and is also used in the proof in this answer.)

Thank you. I guess this is enough!
